# Open Graph breaks Structured Data Testing Tool

Tags: rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool

I added some meta open graph (Twitter, Facebook) to my page, but it breaks my breadcrumb structured data in Structured Data Testing Tool.

[image]

I have no idea where http://ogp.me/* coming from. Here is the [source code](http://pastebin.com/sxQfpiMN) of the page. [The page itself](http://mihalko.eu/dema-corsa-90-green-white-540-mm). The page in [SDTT](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fmihalko.eu%252Fdema-corsa-90-green-white-540-mm)

If I check the breadcrumb code alone in the SDTT, then it is valid.

```
  <meta property="og:title" content="Dema CORSA 9.0 green-white 540 mm" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="mihalko.eu" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://mihalko.eu/image/data/dema-ktlg/B15020.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://mihalko.eu/dema-corsa-90-green-white-540-mm" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="1158837854" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Popis -            Špecifikácia bicykla DEMA CORSA 9.0                 Rám                 "DEMA Road Race Carbon Monocoque, Di2"              Tlmič               -               Vidlica                 DEMA Road Carbon fork / Carbon tapered steerer              Menič               SHIMANO Ultegra RD-6800 SS (11Speed)                Prešmýkač               SHIMANO Ultegra FD-6800,..." />
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="product" />
    <meta property="twitter:site" content="mihalko.eu" />
    <meta property="twitter:creator" content="mihalko.eu" />
    <meta property="twitter:title" content="Dema CORSA 9.0 green-white 540 mm" />
    <meta property="twitter:image" content="http://mihalko.eu/image/data/dema-ktlg/B15020.jpg" />
    <meta property="twitter:description" content="Popis -           Špecifikácia bicykla DEMA CORSA 9.0                 Rám                 "DEMA Road Race Carbon Monocoque, Di2"              Tlmič               -               Vidlica                 DEMA Road Carbon fork / Carbon tapered steerer              Menič               SHIMANO Ultegra RD-6800 SS (11Speed)                Prešmýkač               SHIMANO Ultegra FD-6800,..." />
    <meta property="twitter:label1" content="Cena:" />
    <meta property="twitter:data1" content="2 199,99€" />
    <meta property="twitter:label2" content="Dostupnosť:" />
    <meta property="twitter:data2" content="Dostupné" />
<div class="breadcrumb"
    xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
    <span  typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a href='http://mihalko.eu/index.php?route=common/home' rel="v:url" property="v:title">Úvod</a>
        <span rel='v:child' typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
            <a href='http://mihalko.eu/dema-2015' rel="v:url" property="v:title">DEMA - 2015</a>
            <span rel='v:child' typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
                <a href='http://mihalko.eu/dema-2015/cestne-1' rel="v:url" property="v:title">Cestné</a>
                <span rel="v:child" typeof="v:Breadcrumb" id="lastitem">
                    <a href='http://mihalko.eu/dema-corsa-90-green-white-540-mm' rel="v:url" property="v:title" id="bread-lastitem-link">CORSA 9.0 green-white 540 mm</a>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

This looks like a mix-up on our (Google's) side -- I'll pass it on to the team to check out. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks John!  I tried to contact someone from Google, without success. Now you are here, superb. :)

Comment: Same here, spent 2 days trying to figure out this error.

Comment: I am still seeing this error John.

Answer (score 3):

When checking your document by entering its URL, it reports this error.
But when checking your document by entering its markup (or when re-checking the code the tool fetched from the URL), it reports no errors.

So this seems to be a bug in the Google Structured Data Testing Tool.

Just a guess, but maybe it’s related to the fact that your last breadcrumb URL is the URL you also make OGP statements about. Anyway, as far as I can see, you wouldn’t have to change anything about your RDFa.